# Передача аргументов функцией

Tags: c++, c

Допустим есть функция.

```
void function(int someindex1,int someindex2, ??? type)
{
   for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
     strukt1[i].type = strukt2[i].type
   }
}
```

собственно как можно реализовать передачу названия переменной структуры через аргумент функции

Comment: *Название* переменной вам передавать никуда не надо. Надо передать [указатель на экземпляр структуры](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=c%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%20%D0%B2%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E)

Comment: огромное спасибо.